# How get all objects and their fields as Json

Tags: json, serialize

By means of Schema.getGlobalDescribe.Values () getDescribe ().getName () can receive names of objects.With Using method getDescribe().fields.getMap() we can get fields of object.
It is necessary to serialize a line which would contain all objects and their fields. How it is possible to make it?

Answer (score 2):

Code like this:

```
public class Describer {
    public class Sob {
        public String name;
        public String[] fields;
    }
    public static String serialize() {
        Sob[] sobs = new Sob[] {};
        for (...) {           // Loop over SObject names
           Sob s = new Sob();
           s.name = ...;      // Get name from meta data
           s.fields = ...;    // Get field names from meta data
           sobs.add(s);
        }
        return JSON.serialize(sobs);
    }
}
```

would produce a JSON string that looks like this:

```
[{"name": "Contact", "fields": ["FirstName", "LastName", ...]}, ...]
```

Is that what you want or do you want a copy of all the field meta data? Or something else entirely?

Comment: All information on object is necessary to me: fields, field type, and its values.
Thanks.

Comment: @Pavel You are going to hit governor limits pretty quickly then as you will have to make a describe call for each field. The governor limit I though was 100 of these calls but I vaguely recollect reading somewhere that this may no longer be applied. Best to test before you go much further.

Comment: @Pavel If you want all the field meta data you should see if DescribeFieldResult itself can be serialized to JSON to save you having to reproduce all the fields and assign them. You are aware that the platform has web service APIs to extra this information?

Comment: Thanks for information. I only started studying salesforce therefore I don't know much

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something similar... a json result set of all objects, and their respective fields with all attributes (name, type, id, etc.).  Where do you run your code above from?  Where do you view the result set?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

VFP error: Attempt to de-reference a null object.
Shows only 2 System.debug: debug **__1 and _**_2

```
    public String getserialize(){
        Sob[] sobs = new Sob[]{};
        List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gdMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd){
            Sob s = new Sob();
            s.Name = (String)f.getDescribe().getName();
            System.debug('_____1' + s.Name);
            //sobs.add(s);
            Schema.Describesobjectresult dsr = gdMap.get(s.Name).getDescribe();
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = dsr.fields.getMap();
            for(String key : fieldMap.keySet()){
                System.debug('_____2' + key);
                s.Fields.add(key);
               System.debug('_____3' + key);
            }
            System.debug('_____4' + JSON.serialize(s));
            sobs.add(s);
        }
        System.debug(JSON.serialize(sobs));
        return JSON.serialize(sobs);
    }
```

Comment: The error is because you can only "add" once an array (or list) as assigned to "fields". Or you could do it all in one go by just using "s.Fields = new List<String>(fieldMap.keySet());" which turns the set into a list and then assigns it (eliminating the loop).